# SignalR: How to create and send message to a group from all connected group?

Tags: signalr

I am working on a chat application. I am able to send message to a particular client or all the connected clients. But i want to select 4 Connected user out of 10 connected user and send the for a common message at a time.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor which users are connected bu capturing the `connectionid`, and you can then decide who to send the messages to based on the connected users and their **unique identifier**.

Theres a [good blog post here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users) which shows the idea.

Comment: Thanks christian the blog really helped... Though this is not answer of my question. but is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Clients should be in the particular group.
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection

"You can add connections to groups and send messages to particular groups. Groups are not persisted on the server so applications are responsible for keeping track of what connections are in what groups so things like group count can be achieved."

Comment: I am trying to do the same but I am not getting a way, I am completely new to SignalR and MVC4 any code snippet for doing so???